# Multi join tables with aggregate using main query parameter in subquery

Tags: sql, join, where-clause, aggregate

Quick and easy question.

Say I am joining two tables. I have main query and a sub query. The sub query pulls out one extra column for my resultset. `LEFT JOIN` account for the fact if there are no matching column in `table b` i still want to get all columns from `table a`.

```
select 
    a.*, b.sumb
from 
    ta a 
left join
    (select 
        b.uid, sum(b.amount) as sumb
     from tb b
     group by b.uid) b on a.uid = b.uid
where 
    a.eid = 'value';
```

Works great. Problem I need to limit the list of results that get summed by the inner query based on per `year` grouping. Otherwise the query will just sum everything.

Something like that:

```
select 
    a.*, b.sumb
from 
    ta a 
left join
    (select
        b.uid, sum(b.amount) as sumb
     from tb b
     where b.year = a.year
     group by b.uid) b on a.uid = b.uid
where 
    a.eid = 'value';
```

Unfortunately this `where` clause throws an error

> The multi-part identifier "a.year" could not be bound.

Can someone with the knowhow point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an additional `join` and `group by` column:

```
select a.*, b.sumb
from ta a left join
     (select b.uid, b.year, sum(b.amount) as sumb
      from tb b
      group by b.uid, b.year
     ) b
     on a.uid = b.uid and a.year = b.year
where a.eid = 'value';
```

Comment: Assuming there is Year in a, shouldn't his code work, though?  Or do you have to do something like this through OUTER APPLY or equivalent?  Thanks.

Comment: You would have to use `outer apply`/`cross apply`.  You can't have correlated subqueries as the main subquery in a `from` clause.

Comment: Thanks.  Don't think I've ever tried this but now I know.

Comment: Spot on again. I hope this can be useful to someone else as well.